# powershell doesn't display current directory after conda init

Tags: powershell, anaconda

After executing `conda init`, now every time I open PS, it displays:

```
PS>
```

rather than with the current directory

```
PS C:\Users\Me>
```

How do I make PS show me the current path?

I have a solution to add a PS script like:

```
function prompt {
  $p = Get-Location
  "$p> "
}
```

But the problem is that, though I have my current directory now, I won't be able to see my current env in conda. This means after excuting `conda activate myenv`, current env `myenv` is not displayed, while on the other hand I expect to see:

```
(myenv) PS C:\somePath>
```

Comment: What's your PowerShell Profile got in it?

Comment: Sorry? I don't know what are you talking about. @music2myear

Comment: Powershell has profiles you can use to set all sorts of options in. My first guess would be that Conda added something to your Powershell profile that makes this change. There are several files that build your PS profile. It would be helpful to read this to begin learning about these: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

Short version is to try this in a Powershell session: **Add-CondaEnvironmentToPrompt**

To alter the Powershell prompt, the above answer is correct but these sites have more concise explanations for doint it:
[$Profile-Powershell](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-profile.html)
[Powershell Prompt Function](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-prompt.html)

**The $profile automatic variable will show the location of your Profile.ps1 file:
PS > "$Profile"**

You should find a conda region like:

> region conda initialize ...\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell"
>   "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression ... endregion

If you change 'Out-String' to 'Out-Host' then the commands should be displayed when Powershell is launched. 'Add-CondaEnvironmentToPrompt' should be in there somewhere. Copy and paste that below the conda region in your "$Profile". Change the file back to 'Out-String' and relaunch Powershell.